# Looking for a movie about alien parasites who rely on seduction to reproduce

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror, soft-sci-fi

I remember seeing a movie some time in most likely the 00's (though I have no idea whether it was new or old at the time) about some sort of alien infestation. The key conceit was that these aliens could somehow either infect and mind control humans or shapeshift into them (don't remember which of those two), but regardless of which of those things it was, it resulted in human-looking-things which acted towards nefarious goals.

They seemed to generally rely on seducing normal humans, pretending to want to have sex with them, only to instead plant their alien offspring into those humans. This would end gruesomely for the seduced people, with copious body horror as various alien-looking stuff would grow from and around their corpse before birthing more aliens. I distinctly remember there being multiple moments where a character was seduced, only to be tricked and killed as part of this. I think one of them involved a guy hiring a prostitute (or maybe two prostitutes?) at some sort of brothel. I don't remember whether the guy or the prostitute(s) were the aliens, though, but one of the involved sides died in the process. I think this particular scene was also at the very end of the movie, implying not all aliens died, after previously the protagonists were shown thinking they eradicated the problem.

I think it was supposed to be a horror movie, but I might be misremembering and it could have been a different genre.

Comment: Looking more into this, It might have been one of the Species movies, but I can't pin it down to any particular one, so I'm not sure that was it after all.

Comment: The question's title instantly reminded me of the 1st _Species_ movie with Alfred Molina who, in the movie, died after having an intercourse with a blonde

Comment: In general, humans rely on seduction to reproduce, too, so there's really nothing surprising  or SciFi-ey about that. I guess the "born from corpse" bit isn't quite so normal...

Answer (score 16):

Is this ***[Species II](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120841/)*** (1998)...?

> An astronaut gets infected with alien DNA during the first mission on Mars and runs amok on earth. Preston and Laura team up with a peaceful, genetically re-engineered Sil to track the monster down.

The plot centres on Commander Patrick Ross -- an astronaut and the son of a US senator -- who returns to Earth from mankind's first Mars landing infected with the DNA of the alien species from the first film, who'd apparently visited the red planet a billion years prior.

No one initially knows he's infected, and he proceeds to have sex with various human women -- including several prostitutes -- in attempt to produce as many children as possible. Between roughly the 48 and 53 minute mark in the film, we see him pick up a street walker, visit a love motel, and pick up a pole dancer at a strip club. You can see the street walker getting into Ross' car at around the 1 minute mark in the trailer below.

Ross' children gestate at an accelerated rate, eventually tearing their way out of their mothers' bellies. He then takes the children to a barn formerly owned by his late mother, where they become enveloped in cocoons that'll allow them to rapidly grow into adults. He produces around twenty kids in total.

The US government had also grown a genetic duplicate of the main female alien from the first film, naming her Eve. She was to be used as a test subject to identify any vulnerabilities of the alien species, but she forms a telepathic link with Ross, and eventually escapes the facility she's being held in, seeking him out to have sex with.

She finds him at the barn, and they do indeed have sex. The authorities followed her, and while Ross and Eve are doing their thing, they proceed to kill most of Ross' children, who're still in their cocoons. Ross and Eve are subsequently killed as well.

In the closing scene, Eve's bloody corpse is loaded into the back of an ambulance, and after the doors are closed, we see that one of Ross' children is still alive and has managed to sneak into the ambulance with her. Eve's belly is also shown to be rapidly expanding, implying the imminent birth of another child.

Comment: Hm. Both Species and Decoys seem plausible. Short of watching all movies in both series, I'm not sure how to disambiguate them, so I'm not sure which answer to accept. In the meantime I'll wait a bit longer to see if an answer can more clearly pin down what it was. It's also possible that my memory mixed together Species and Decoys since I'd have watched them 20 years ago, though.

Comment: And of course there also was the [Species](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114508/), which would have been my first guess.

Comment: @Mash - There's no hurry to accept. I'd suggest watching both of the films proposed here when it's convenient, then returning to the thread to confirm whether either answer is correct or not. I doubt it's _Decoys_, as I don't recall there being any prostitutes in that. I also doubt it's any of the other _Species_ films, as I don't recall there being any prostitutes in those either. Note that _Species II_ is the only one where the main alien is male and has sex with human women (including prostitutes). In the other films, the main alien is female and has sex with men (not prostitutes).

Comment: That sounds like a very close fit then @LogicDictates. I'll take a look to confirm when I have enough free time. Thanks.

Comment: iirc, an older 80s movie like this would be 'Liquid Sky'.

Answer (score 9):

Are you remembering **[Decoys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoys_(film))**?

[image: Decoys movie poster]

Decoys is a 2004 science-fiction horror film directed by Matthew Hastings and starring Kim Poirier and Nicole Eggert. (It also spawned a 2007 sequel, [Decoys 2: Alien Seduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoys_2:_Alien_Seduction).)

The movie's plot description on Wikipedia seems like a partial match. The story involves aliens disguised as human women attempting to seduce human men, only to violently impregnate the men with ovipositors. The men usually die.

There is a scene with two women (aliens) though it is not clear they are prostitutes, and it is not the last scene, so it is not an exact match for your description:

> Luke Callahan and Roger, two college freshmen and virgins, are
> desperate to get laid. While doing their laundry after drinking too
> much beer, Luke meets two seductive girls named Lily and Constance.
> When Lily deliberately leaves a roll of quarters in the laundry, an
> inebriated and horny Luke goes to return them to her. He finds her
> room is unlocked and he decides to sneak in, finding that it is very
> cold inside. But when the girls suddenly return, he decides to hide in
> the closet. Luke watches as the girls open the windows and let the
> cold winter air surround them, seemingly arousing and comforting them
> as they strip naked, much to Luke's amusement. He then watches in
> horror and confusion as reptilian tentacles unfold from their chests
> and sexually arouse them while Constance sprays Lily down with a can
> of liquid nitrogen. Luke, horrified and intrigued, decides to get to
> the bottom of the mystery.

The final scene does, though, include the revelation that a character previously assumed to be human is not, so again a partial match:

> Alex takes Luke to her apartment, and the two profess their love for
> each other. They take off their clothes and prepare to have sex. Alex
> mounts Luke, and tells him she can finally have her way with him.
> There's a sudden flashback to the very beginning of the movie when the
> jock finds the dead men. He looks up and sees Alex who then says
> "You're early". Luke realizes Alex is an alien, minutes too late. He
> screams as she pins him down and her tentacles appear. The camera
> zooms out of the room as Luke's screams fade away as he is presumably
> raped and impregnated.

Comment: Been a while since I watched this one, but I don't think there were any prostitutes in it. I believe the aliens were disguised as female college students, and their victims were male students.

Comment: Hm. Both Species and Decoys seem plausible. Short of watching all movies in both series, I'm not sure how to disambiguate them, so I'm not sure which answer to accept. In the meantime I'll wait a bit longer to see if an answer can more clearly pin down what it was. It's also possible that my memory mixed together Species and Decoys since I'd have watched them 20 years ago, though.

Answer (score 3):

This made me think of [**Under The Skin**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1441395/)

[image: Under The Skin poster 2013]

Granted it's not 20 years old, but it is 10. Fantastic, eerie film.

> Disguising itself as a human female, an extraterrestrial drives around Scotland attempting to lure unsuspecting men into her van. Once there, she seduces and sends them into another dimension where they are nothing more than meat.

There are a few similarities to what you remember, although it's not really about shapeshifting (or is it?) and although there is a particularly memorable body horror scene towards the end, some of the violence is implied.

The start of the film sets up the replication thing but it is questioned rather than outright answered. The end of the film does leave some questions unanswered about what was going on with the motorcyclist and whether the alien is still around.

> It’s implied that in the context of the story, the alien creature is not completely destroyed. In all likelihood, the alien will take a new form as it inhabits a different body, and has a completely different experience. During the opening sequence, the space-bound entity was seen coming to Earth. It’s unclear whether its intent was to travel to other planets, or stay on Earth. It’s also unclear if there are any other extraterrestrial creatures that may be exploring other parts of the world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  The question seems to make a major point of the body horror of the alien reproduction method.  Does the alien reproduce by consuming human bodies?

Comment: The film doesn't show reproduction but it does show the alien peeling off her own skin entirely, like a glove. The alien pushes the humans into void-like space where they are being 'digested' for a lack of a better word.

Comment: I don't think there were any pocket dimensions. The victims remained firmly on Earth and could be found by other humans.

Comment: Ah I see, this film sprung to mind, but a swing and a miss.

Comment: This is not it. While Isserley does lure humans using sex appeal, this is just a lure, it has nothing to do with reproduction. The movie is slightly different but in the novel it's clear her species is using humans as cattle, for their meat.

Answer (score 2):

Could be [Slither](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slither_(2006_film)):

> A meteorite brings a malevolent, sentient extraterrestrial parasite to Earth. The parasite enters the town of Wheelsy, South Carolina, where it infects wealthy resident Grant Grant by **taking over his body and absorbing his mind. With the alien in control of him, Grant begins to transform into a grotesque, tentacled monstrosity. He also abducts and infects a local woman, Brenda, to serve as a breeder for his alien larvae.** His wife Starla becomes suspicious over the changes in his appearance and behavior, leading to Grant attacking her. When the police arrive to rescue Starla, Grant flees.
>
> During their search for Grant, a posse led by police chief Bill Pardy discovers Brenda, whose body has become inhumanly bloated from the larvae growing inside her. The slug-like larvae burst from her body and infests everyone in town, except Starla, Bill, Mayor Jack MacReady, and teenager Kylie Strutemyer. Those infected by the larvae become part of a hive mind controlled by Grant, who intends to consume all lifeforms until only his consciousness remains. However, Grant also retains his love for his wife and seeks to be reunited with her. The survivors deduce that killing Grant will eliminate the rest of the aliens before they are attacked by the infected townspeople. Bill and Kylie escape, but Starla and Jack are captured.
>
> Armed with a grenade to kill the monster, Bill and Kylie head to Grant's home, where the infected are being absorbed by the increasingly-mutated Grant. Jack and others are turned into breeders for more larvae, while Grant keeps Starla uninfected in the hope of regaining her love. After waking up, Starla arms herself with a sharp brush and goes downstairs to find Grant. She tricks him into believing she still loves him and stabs him with the brush. Grant becomes angry and throws her across the room while Bill tries to use the grenade, only for Grant to knock it into the pool. Grant subdues Kylie with a couch and attempts to infect Bill with his tentacles. While one of the tentacles stabs Bill in the stomach, he attaches the other tentacle to a propane tank. Filled with flammable gas, Grant is shot by Starla and explodes, killing the rest of the aliens in the process. With everyone else in Wheelsy dead, the three survivors head off to seek help.
>
> **In a post-credits scene, a cat approaches Grant's remains and becomes infected by the alien parasite.**

Comment: I don't think the aliens in Slither rely on seduction to reproduce ;)